# ROUND functions calculating wrong?

Tags: function, rounding

I really want somebody, who can explain me, why `ROUND` function is calculating on this way. I don't think, I found something what others not in the last 40 years, just I can't believe it is works like this, and I really want to know the reason of this.

Of course, I tried to search here, and the web, but I found only users created round function problems.

The whole thing is came from here, when I want to check the `ROUND` function syntax in `MySql`.

I've found this explanation on [this](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-round-function.php) site.

[image]

I really wondered, is the function checks only the third decimal place, and do not parse the fourth, when I want to round up to 2 decimals.

So I've made a test in `MySql` and `PHP` also, the results are the same.

```
var_dump(round(4.4449, 2));
var_dump (round(4.445, 2));
```

Output:

```
float 4.44
float 4.45
```

How is it possible? I thought:

```
4.4449
    ^^ <-- this 49 should be 50 so 5.
```

Ok, I really do not want to calculating a ballistic track of a rocket with PHP, but if it is real money, where there are millions of transactions on a webshop, I think, a many a little makes a mickle.

Please tell me, there are something because I can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: I fail to see the problem. If the *next* digit after the desired precision is <5, rounding is downwards. If it is >=5, rounding is up. The digits after the one under consideration are not important. Note that in your `4.4449` example you want to round **twice**, which is a no-no.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but since 4.4449 is closer to 4.44 than 4.45, I would expect `ROUND(4.4449, 2)` to return 4.44 as it does. In your last example, you're rounding 4.4449 to 3 d.p., which would indeed be 4.445.

Comment: since 49 != 50 why do you say "this 49 should be 50"?

Comment: Ok, i've got it, thank you guys, I sad, I can't see the woods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is right, rounding says clearly "if decimal is bigger or equal 0,5, raise it to 1, otherwise set it to 0".

Is `0,4999999999999 >= 0,5`?